# MongoDB 4.4, Java driver 4.2.3 - InsertManyResult.getInsertedIds() not returning IDs for all inserted documents

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver, mongo-java

I am trying to retrieve values of `_id` for inserted documents after successful `InsertMany` operation. To achieve this I am using `InsertManyResult.getInsertedIds()`. While this approach works most of the time there are cases where not all `_id` values are retrieved.

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong but I would assume that `InsertManyResult.getInsertedIds()` returns `_id` for *all* the documents inserted.

#### Problem details

I am inserting 1000 documents in MongoDB in two batches of 500 documents. Each document is approx 1 MB in size.

After batch is inserted using `InsertMany` I attempt to read values of `_id` via `InsertManyResult.getInsertedIds()` and save it to a collection for later use.

I would assume that after inserting *500* documents via `InsertMany` the `InsertManyResult.getInsertedIds()` would return *500* `_id` values. It is however returning only *16* `_id` values out of *500*.

When I check the Mongo collection directly via Mongo Shell I see that all records were successfully inserted. There is *1000* documents in my test collection. I am just unable to get the `_id` of all the inserted document via `InsertManyResult.getInsertedIds()`. I only get *32* `_id` for 1000 documents inserted.

#### JSON structure

To replicate the issue I have exactly **one** JSON which is approx 1 MB in size which looks like this.

```
{
  "textVal" : "RmKHtEMMzJDXgEApmWeoZGRdZJZerIj1",
  "intVal" : 161390623,
  "longVal" : "98213019054010317",
  "timestampVal" : "2020-12-31 23:59:59.999",
  "numericVal" : -401277306,
  "largeArrayVal" : [ "MMzJDXg", "ApmWeoZGRdZJZerI", "1LhTxQ", "adprPSb1ZT", ..., "QNLkBZuXenmYE77"]

}
```

Note that key `largeArrayVal` is holding almost all the data. I have omitted most of the values for readability.

#### Sample code

The code below parses JSON shown above into a `Document` which is then inserted to MongoDB via `InsertMany`. After that is done I try to get inserted `_id` using `InsertManyResult.getInsertedIds()`.

```
private static final int MAX_DOCUMENTS = 1000;
private static final int BULK_SIZE = 500;

private static List<ObjectId> insertBatchReturnIds(List<Document> insertBatch)
{
  List<ObjectId> insertedIds = new ArrayList<ObjectId>();
  InsertManyResult insertManyResult;

  insertManyResult = mongoClient.getDatabase(MONGO_DATABASE).getCollection(MONGO_COLLECTION).insertMany(insertBatch);
  insertManyResult.getInsertedIds().forEach((k,v) -> insertedIds.add(v.asObjectId().getValue()));

  System.out.println("Batch inseted:");
  System.out.println(" - Was acknowladged: " + Boolean.toString(insertManyResult.wasAcknowledged()).toUpperCase());
  System.out.println(" - InsertManyResult.getInsertedIds().size(): " + insertManyResult.getInsertedIds().size());

  return insertedIds;
}

private static void insertDocuments()
{
  int documentsInserted = 0;
  List<Document> insertBatch = new ArrayList<Document>();
  List<ObjectId> insertedIds = new ArrayList<ObjectId>();
  final String largeJson = loadLargeJsonFromFile("d:\\test-sample.json");

  System.out.println("Starting INSERT test...");
  while (documentsInserted < MAX_DOCUMENTS)
  {
    insertBatch.add(Document.parse(largeJson));
    documentsInserted++;

    if (documentsInserted % BULK_SIZE == 0)
    {
     insertedIds.addAll(insertBatchReturnIds(insertBatch));
     insertBatch.clear();
    }
  }
  if (insertBatch.size() > 0)
    insertedIds.addAll(insertBatchReturnIds(insertBatch));
  System.out.println("INSERT test finished");

  System.out.println(String.format("Expected IDs retrieved: %d. Actual IDs retrieved: %d.", MAX_DOCUMENTS, insertedIds.size()));
  if (insertedIds.size() != MAX_DOCUMENTS)
    throw new IllegalStateException("Not all _ID were returned for each document in batch");
}
```

### Sample output

```
Starting INSERT test...
Batch inseted:
 - Was acknowladged: TRUE
 - InsertManyResult.getInsertedIds().size(): 16
Batch inseted:
 - Was acknowladged: TRUE
 - InsertManyResult.getInsertedIds().size(): 16
INSERT test finished
Expected IDs retrieved: 1000. Actual IDs retrieved: 32.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not all _ID were returned for each document in batch
```

#### My questions

1. Is `InsertManyResult.getInsertedIds()` meant to return `_id` for *all* documents inserted?
2. Is the way I am using `InsertManyResult.getInsertedIds()` correct?
3. Could size of the inserted JSON be a factor here?
4. How should I use `InsertManyResult` to get `_id` for inserted documents?

### Note

I am aware that I can either read `_id` after `Document.parse` as it is the driver that generates this or I can select `_id` after documents were inserted.
I would like to know how can this be achieved using `InsertManyResult.getInsertedIds()` as it seems to be made to fit this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the Java driver, and it's being tracked in https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-4436 (reported on January 5, 2022).

Answer (score 0):

Your documents are 1 mb large, hence no more than 16 of them fit into a single command. The driver does split the full set of documents into batches automatically but you appear to be reading ids from one batch at a time, therefore the problem is likely one of the following:

- There is a driver issue where it doesn't merge the batch results together prior to returning the results to your application
- The driver is giving you the results one batch at a time, hence you do get all of the ids but not in the segments you were expecting (in which case there is no bug but you do need to work with batches as they are provided by the driver)

The following test in Ruby works as expected, producing 100 ids:

```rb
c = Mongo::Client.new(['localhost:14920'])

docs = [{a: 'x'*1_000_000}]*100
res = c['foo'].insert_many(docs)

p res.inserted_ids.length
pp res.inserted_ids
```

Comment: It is entirely possible that I am using `InsertManyResult` wrong. Could you please point me to some documentation that would provide details on how to read all the segments?
I did not find anything suggesting multiple segments must be read to `InsertManyResult` in [Mongo java driver documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/tutorials/perform-write-operations/#insert-multiple-documents) nor in the [Mongo Java driver API - InsertManyResult](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/apidocs/mongodb-driver-core/com/mongodb/client/result/InsertManyResult.html).

Comment: I don't write Java so can't help you with that unfortunately. I added working Ruby code, if the equivalent Java code doesn't work you may consider creating a ticket at https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/java.